# Show that the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x + x$ is invertible

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

> Show that$$
> f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x + x$$is invertible.

How do I continue with this?

I've tried with taking the derivative and taken the fact that$$
f'(x)=\cos 2x +1 \ge 0.$$

Is this enough? I'm not sure since it can also equal $0$...

Comment: If you show that it equals $0$ only for discrete values of $x$, then that should be enough.

Comment: Hm, why would that prove the invertible part? To show invertibility, I need to prove that the function is injective. In this case I do it by taking the derivative and try to show that the function is increasing. I cannot relate why discrete values of x that equals 0 would prove that part.

Comment: Because if the derivative is $0$ for discrete values only, then $f$ is never monotone, which implies it is in fact *strictly* increasing. Therefore it is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how fussy you are. Suppose that $a\lt b$. We want to show that $f(a)\lt f(b)$.

Step a *tiny* amount to the right of $a$, say to $c$, where $c\lt b$ and there is no $x$ strictly between $a$ and $c$ such that $f'(x)=0$. Then $f(a)\lt f(c)$. Also, $f(c)\le f(b)$, so $f(a)\lt f(b)$.

Comment: Yeah, that seems logical. It is also easy to explain when we have a trigonometric function to deal with. :-)

Comment: @JulianAssange: You are being careful in worrying about the fact that $f'(x)$ can be $0$. The proof I gave in the post can be adapted to show that there is no need to worry unless $f'(x)=0$ in an *interval*.

Comment: Okay, thanks Andre!